# How to push for review?

Tags: git, push, gerrit, review

I want to push some code change for review to a remote repository. We are using gerrit. How do I do ?

I tried to install git-review and use but I got a lot of errors and when I tried

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

I got:

```
missing Change-Id in message hook
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [missing Change-Id in commit message footer for git-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609744/missing-change-id-in-commit-message-footer-for-git-review)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgerrit%5D+missing+Change-Id+in+message+hook

Answer (score 3):

Your Gerrit server is configured to require a Change-Id in the commit message.

You need to add a Change-Id line to your commit and then re-execute the "push" command. To add the Change-Id automatically you need to have the "commit-msg" hook installed on your local repository.

1) Install the "commit-msg" hook

```
gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)
curl --create-dirs -Lo ${gitdir}/hooks/commit-msg https://GERRIT-SERVER/tools/hooks/commit-msg
chmod u+x ${gitdir}/hooks/commit-msg
```

2) Add the Change-Id to the commit message

```
git commit --amend
```

3) Push the new commit to Gerrit

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

See more information about Change-Ids at the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html).